# how to get value in textboxes selecting dropdown list value?

Tags: javascript

hi i want to display value in textbox selected by dropdown value. suppose i selected sql
 i got the value like jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=falsein jdbc url textbox.com.mysql.jdbc.Driver driver name in driver class textbox.
    this  type of code i want

```
      <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Database Type</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><select name="Database Type" onclick="fillData()" id="sel_value">
                                <option value="DB2">DB2</option>
                                <option value="Derby">Derby</option>
                                <option value="Hypersonic">Hypersonic</option>
                                <option value="Ingres">Ingres</option>
                                <option value="MySQL">MySQL</option>
                                <option value="Oracle">Oracle</option>
                                <option value="P6Spy">P6Spy</option>
                                <option value="PostgreSQL">PostgreSQL</option>
                                <option value="SQL Server">SQL Server</option>
                                <option value="Sybase">Sybase</option>
                        </select>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>JDBC URL(required)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="jdbcUrl" style="width: 550px;" id="jdbcUrl"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>JDBC Driver Class Name(Required)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="text" style="width: 550px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>username</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="text" style="width: 550px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>password</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="password" name="text" style="width: 550px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: Change onclick="fillData()" to onChange="fillData(this.value)"

Answer (score 0):

Replace the onclick with onchange. Here try this code:

```
<select name="Database Type" onchange="fillData()" id="sel_value">
      <option value="DB2">DB2</option>
      <option value="Derby">Derby</option>
      <option value="Hypersonic">Hypersonic</option>
      <option value="Ingres">Ingres</option>
      <option value="MySQL">MySQL</option>
      <option value="Oracle">Oracle</option>
      <option value="P6Spy">P6Spy</option>
      <option value="PostgreSQL">PostgreSQL</option>
      <option value="SQL Server">SQL Server</option>
      <option value="Sybase">Sybase</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function fillData(){
    alert($('#sel_value').val()); 
}
```